# Unity rotate camera using touch - Mobile

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a camera following where the player goes by using:

```
void Awake() {
         target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
     }
     void Update () {
         transform.position = target.position + offset;

     }
```

the player movement is being taken from a joystick using the following

```
myRBody.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * moveForce,
                                       myRBody.velocity.y,
                                       joystick.Vertical * moveForce);
  if (joystick.Horizontal != 0f || joystick.Vertical != 0f)
         {


             transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(myRBody.velocity);

         }
```

I am trying to use the screen to let the player rotate the camera around them. I tried adding an image on the canvas and making that the area the player can use to move the camera and took the input from that to change the camera position but I am having trouble getting that to work. Does anyone have an example on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete tutorial on [what you asked for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW1lxrgHgG8)

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the transform.position of the camera on every frame. It means you are 'teleporting' it to a new position on every Update.
You need to recalculate the Camera offset when an input is detected and then set the transform.position.